# Jdbc source connector for kafka

Tags: jdbc, apache-kafka, rdbms, connector, confluent-platform

I am getting this below error while running kafka jdbc connector

ERROR Stopping after connector error (org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectStandalone:108) java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/calcite/avatica/UnregisteredDriver at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763) at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142) at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467) at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73) at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368) at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362) at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361) at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335) at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:411) at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader.loadClass(DelegatingClassLoader.java:311) at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:411) at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.PluginClassLoader.loadClass(PluginClassLoader.java:62) at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348) at java.sql.DriverManager.isDriverAllowed(DriverManager.java:556) at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:661) at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247) at io.confluent.connect.jdbc.source.JdbcSourceConnectorConfig$TableRecommender.validValues(JdbcSourceConnectorConfig.java:482) at io.confluent.connect.jdbc.source.JdbcSourceConnectorConfig$CachingRecommender.validValues(JdbcSourceConnectorConfig.java:521) at org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigDef.validate(ConfigDef.java:595) at org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigDef.validate(ConfigDef.java:616) at org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigDef.validate(ConfigDef.java:516) at org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigDef.validateAll(ConfigDef.java:499) at org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigDef.validate(ConfigDef.java:481) at org.apache.kafka.connect.connector.Connector.validate(Connector.java:133) at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.AbstractHerder.validateConnectorConfig(AbstractHerder.java:265) at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.standalone.StandaloneHerder.putConnectorConfig(StandaloneHerder.java:163) at org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectStandalone.main(ConnectStandalone.java:102) Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.calcite.avatica.UnregisteredDriver at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381) at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335) at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ... 32 more

Before this i have tested for twitter and ftp connector it was working after completed this two connector again i had run the jdbc its showing this error Previously it was working, after i run the twitter and ftp connector it is showing this jar issue

Comment: This either means the driver could not be loaded because of class version errors (wrong java versions), or missing dependencies on the classpath, or you have a weird classloading issue (given this exception originates inside a check in `DriverManager` itself. Without more information, we can't help you.

Comment: Please help us by providing code and any other relevant information.

Comment: To run the connectors --> sudo ./bin/connect-standalone ./etc/schema-registry/connect-avro-standalone.properties ./etc/kafka-connect-jdbc/source-quickstart-postgres.properties

Comment: Please do not use comments to add information, **edit** your question

Comment: 1) Don't post your database credentials in plain text! 2) You're using Postgres, so I don't think Calcite should be loading itself

Comment: Even i dropped the calcite jar also , it is showing the same error still